# Is it possible to add mulitple entries to one line in a listbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Right now you can add the data to the listbox, thanks to the stack overflow communinity, i'm not sure if it is possible to have all entries on the same line in the listbox

I know if i use one entry box everything will be on one line

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def add_task():
    task = name_input.get()
    start_dte = start_date_input.get()
    due_dte = due_date_input.get()
    pri = pri_input.get()
    stat = status_input.get()
    # end

    listbox.insert(1, task)
    listbox.insert(1, start_dte)
    listbox.insert(1, due_dte)
    listbox.insert(1, pri)
    listbox.insert(1, stat)

def clear_all():
    listbox.delete(0,END)

root = Tk()
root.title("Todo list") # title of the application
    #root.geometry("900x400") # size of the application
titlelbl=Label(root, text = 'Welcome to your To-do-list', font='Times 30  bold').grid(row=0, column=5)#pack(),place(x = 25, y = 30)


name_input = StringVar()
start_date_input = StringVar()
due_date_input = StringVar()
pri_input = StringVar()
status_input = StringVar()

Label(root, text = "Name").grid(row = 6, column = 4)#pack()
name = Entry(root, textvariable = name_input)
name.grid(row = 7, column = 4)#pack()

Label(root, text = "Start date").grid(row = 6, column = 5)#pack()
start_date = Entry(root, textvariable = start_date_input)
start_date.grid(row = 7, column = 5)#pack()

Label(root, text = "Due date").grid(row = 6, column = 6)#pack()
due_date = Entry(root, textvariable = due_date_input).grid(row = 7, column = 6)#pack()

Label(root, text = "Priority").grid(row = 6, column = 7)#pack()
priority = Entry(root, textvariable = pri_input)
priority.grid(row = 7, column = 7)#pack()

Label(root, text = "Status").grid(row = 6, column = 8)#pack()
status = Entry(root, textvariable = status_input)
status.grid(row = 7, column = 8)#pack()

add_btn = Button(root, text = 'Add', width = 10, height = 3, command = add_task)
add_btn.grid(row = 9, column= 7)#pack()#place(x = 15, y = 50)

listbox = Listbox(root,font=('', 12), width = 60, height = 10)
listbox.grid(row = 3, column = 5)#pack()
listbox.insert(1, 'Name          Start date          Due Date       Priority        Status')

Button(root, text = 'Clear',width = 10, height = 3, command = clear_all).grid(row =9, column =10)

root.mainloop()
```

The expected result is for the user to enter the data from the entry boxes into the lisbox as one line.
Instead because they all have it as insert at 1 they go underneath each other

Answer (score 1):

One way you could achieve this is by making your entry a string first then inserting.

```
def add_task():
    task = name_input.get()
    start_dte = start_date_input.get()
    due_dte = due_date_input.get()
    pri = pri_input.get()
    stat = status_input.get()
    test_string = task+"          "+start_dte+"          "+due_dte+"          "+pri+"          "+stat
    listbox.insert(1,test_string)
```

just like you made your headers in your list box by making it a string.

Comment: Thanks for the help ill just need to fix how far apart they are